Calculating the wattage of a speaker protection light bulb
I have a very old musician's singing system in my hobby room. Yesterday one of the speakers broke down. In search of the cause, I finally opened the speaker box and found two light bulbs inside. One of them had burned out. They are probably used as overload protection. Unfortunately, the label on the light bulbs is no longer legible. The only thing I could decipher is 24 volts.
Does anyone have instructions on how to calculate the wattage of the light bulb depending on the chassis? I couldn't find anything about it on the Internet. This technology is probably pretty outdated.

We're going to need pictures at an absolute minimum. If you can figure out a schematic, please do; a lightbulb for a purpose like that is pretty unusual. Could it be a neon lamp?

speaker ohms?  power out rating W?  diameter of bulb? series lamps?

(I've heard of this use of incandescent lamp, esp. with PA - when a fuse blows, sound ceses; when the lamp glows/lights, it just gets less loud) I'd try to calculate a useful upper limit for speaker/"driver" current, and start experimenting with twice that  amperage/calculated lamp wattage.

Apply nominal voltage to the surviving bulb & measure current.

In addition to the fine answers below -- if a fuse blows, it's often a good idea to track down why it blew before you change it.  Were you playing especially loud?  Did the amplifier break?  At the very least, if you swap in a new bulb and it immediately burns out -- you have bigger problems than a one-time loss of a light bulb.

Measuring the good one is the right answer. You can also search for replacement bulbs in the required form-factor (tubular?) to see what discrete wattages are available.

Also keep in mind Tim’s comment- if you swap the two bulbs and there is something wrong with one channel you could blow the remaining good bulb and not only have the amplifier channel to repair but no good bulb to measure.

Duplicating the good one will result in another bulb failure like before as they won't be matched unless you replace both.  Even still the bulbs should last a long time as they should never be operating near full power if selected properly. I hope they don't need 12:1 compression. The audio will be ducking like crazy

Did you want to use a different chassis?

No problem, just replace it with a LED bulb, I'm sure it'll work fine... surely newer must be better!

I gather you read the bulb rating but didn't tell us, nor the speaker ohms or relative loudness

Since *One of them had burned out," you just need to check the current through the good lamp at 24 V, and replace the one that failed with a similar lamp.
This must be done at the rated voltage, since tungsten filamant incandescent lamps are nonlinear resistors -- using Ohm's law at a different voltage would give a false current rating.
In fact that is the reason for use of the lamp: it operates as an audio compressor/limiter at high volume. The resistance of a tungsten lamp may be 10 times higher at design voltage compared to that at lower voltage.
That said, vibration inside the speaker enclosure likely shortens the life of the lamp. Consider buying a spare or two.

what bulb power did you estimate?

@D.A.S., how does one estimate power? One tests the current draw and, knowing it's at 24 V, calculates the power.

I mean if you were designing it for a living room into an 8 Ohm speaker and makes a rough estimate.  Do you start with 1 Ohm cold or 8 Ohms cold for example and with two 24V bulbs what power is that. That was my question. Not the obvious.

For two 24V current limiting bulbs in series with a speaker, the bulbs will heat up faster than the speaker coils and thus protect them from overheating and limiting the speaker output power.
Without amp/speaker specs, I computed the following;



vpk
speaker
Pwr Avg No bulb
24V Bulb Pwr * 2
PD bulb
Pd speaker
pOut
PBul * 2 / PD Speaker




40
8
100
20
7.7
0.7
8.4
3.50%





30
10.8
1.5
12.3
5.00%





40
13.3
2.6
16.0
6.50%





50
15.8
3.8
19.6
7.60%


30
8
56
20
4.9
0.5
5.4
2.50%





30
6.9
1.1
8.0
3.67%





40
8.5
1.9
10.4
4.75%





50
9.9
2.9
12.8
5.80%


20
8
50
20
3
0.2
3.2
1.00%





30
4.22
0.4
4.7
1.43%





40
5.4
0.8
6.2
1.88%





50
7.6
1.2
8.8
2.40%


30
4
112
20
5.3
0.3
5.6
1.38%





30
7.6
0.6
8.2
2.00%





40
9.6
1.0
10.6
2.50%





50
11.5
1.5
13.0
3.00%



They must be identical bulbs otherwise the lower rated one will draw much more power.
I simulated with one 48V bulb but showing 2 x 24V bulbs here in computation.

Thanks for your great support. What amp/speaker specs do you need to calculate exacter?
And do you have a special software for the calculation?
Thanks again

I indicated already and software is linked above

"speaker ohms? {amp} power out rating W? diameter of bulb?  ALso is there a desired limiting power output? Like 5% of amp rating ??
